# Change of real eigenvalues under symmetric perturbation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, symmetric-matrices

Given a real matrix $A$ and a real diagonal matrix $D$.

Assuming $A$ has $k$ real eigenvalues. Will $A + D$ have $k$ real eigenvalues as well?

What if $D$ is symmetric?

Comment: Welcome to [math.se].
Can you please [edit] your post and write your attempts at solving the problem?
If your question is clear and focused on your specific difficulty and you show your effort in solving the problem, it's more likely to get good and helping answers.
By the way, take the opportunity to take the [Tour], if you haven't done it already. See also some tips on 
[ask], on 
[formatting help](https://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help) 
and on writing down equations using 
[LaTeX / MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to both questions is no.

For instance, consider
$$
A = \pmatrix{-2&-1\\1&1}, \quad D = \pmatrix{3&0\\0&0}.
$$
$A$ has $2$ real eigenvalues, $A + D$ has none.